# Inserting new associations after the last associations in a file in a Rails generator using a Regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, thor, rubular

I've been trying to insert a few new associations into an existing model using the `insert_into_file` method in a custom generator.  For aesthetic reasons, and to avoid hard-coding anything, I would like to insert them after the last ones found.  I tried to implement this with a regexp that works in Rubular, but not when I run the generator:

```
def add_associations_to_other_things
  content = <<-CONTENT
has_many :things
  CONTENT
  inject_into_file "app/models/other_things.rb", \
  content, \
  :after => /(?:(has_and_belongs_to_many|has_many|has_one|belongs_to)[^\n]*$)(?!.*has_and_belongs_to_many|has_many|has_one|belongs_to.*\z)/m
end
```

In words, this should find the last association out to a newline that is not followed by any more associations.  The `m` option means that the dots in the negative lookahead should be treated as newlines and so should look out to the end of the file.  In Rubular, the final association is selected, but when the generator is run, the content is inserted after every association.

What's wrong with my regexp?